# Running Windows Blender on a Mac

Tags: osx

I plug in I need to use (an MDB importer) does not work on the Mac version of Blender

So i need to run a Windows version on my Mac - ive tried Crossover and Winebottler but not been able to get a Windows version working

Has anybody managed to do this for whatever reason?

Comment: Bootcamp works fine for that ; but it's kinda heavy solution. Maybe VirtualBox ?

Comment: Have checked out [this page on the Blender website?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUmIr.png)